# Firebase increase value without reading previous value?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an ios application using Firebase it has huge users. I need to update particular field value in Firebase database based on user's response. Is there a way to increase particular field' value by one(1) without reading its current value. What will happen when several users trying to increase value of same field concurrently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a client app, you cannot increment a value without reading it.  If there are multiple writers, the last writer's value overwrites everything else.

If you want to safely increment a value when there are concurrent writers of the same value, use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: How about from Cloud Function?

Comment: @Zenko You can use transactions in Firebase Admin like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions)